# Not able to infer types for this map

Tags: javascript, typescript, typescript-typings

I have been trying to get my head around defining types for the `TESTS` object below in typescript but still can't figure out anything. It would be really helpful if anyone's aware of what should be it's type and also explain me how since I'm just getting started with `ts`. Here is the object I'm talking about:

```
const TESTS = [
   ['reminderEmail', new Map([  
     ['subject', { test: 'equal', expected: 'Kindly complete your setup' }],
     ['headers', new Map([
       ['X-Link', { test: 'equal', expected: 'someUrl' }],
       ['X-Template-Name', { test: 'equal', expected: 'reminderFirst' }],
       ['X-Template-Version', { test: 'equal', expected: 'someVersion' }],
     ])],
     ['html', [
       { test: 'include', expected: "Here&#x27;s your reminder" },
       { test: 'include', expected: 'someUrl' },
       { test: 'include', expected: 'someUrl' },
       { test: 'include', expected: 'device' },
     ]],
     ['text', [
       { test: 'include', expected: "Here's your reminder" },
       { test: 'notInclude', expected: 'someUrl' },
       { test: 'notInclude', expected: 'someUrl' },
       { test: 'notInclude', expected: 'utm_source=email' },
     ]],
   ])],       
 ];
```

The link to the typescript playground is [here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYewdgzgLgBAKgUQMpyTAvDA2gKBvrAcgCcBTAWwEswATU4hcgQ0oBtCAaGMUgdxgCyTAA4AKLPjz4ChCAFcARgCtSwKJxgBvGFFLQAXDEKkAjnKbsupAB7DVumocIBpajVYBPGKHLDWpXRgPEDliGAgAuWFCGABfAF0OKWkiAAtSJjpiCA0efiExXGliogANAFoAGWoAaw1tXQMjU3NLGBs7NVJHIwgQclIAVWJ2OMTkksIKuAo-Jl1ygDkmAfqdPSgnFosNDvtupzIqWnoAMUps9TGk4pSp8pnfVnnScoA1eghKcDXGzeazDsrLZ9j1ZP1SB9st8wDEEjdivEAJTjW5pKDkNpFW5adZNQjUYCsOR0XYgro9ABEAAl6KQAGQAYmsACYAOwAbggQRCYSObnolLiCNuDQ2TkJxNJwM6DicfQGw1GsRFxTF%20MlJNIZNlB16EKVcNV0nV-wJYCJWp1oKcdAAbpRgNrhRMYPFUZNdNZ1FxsaK8WbNdL2uS5TAaXTZDzQjB%20SdiEKVa78KanGAQFAAJIWqXamU2-WKkZG5O4v5pjPZy3BvYU%20UG4sunFl8VGdNZnNW-N1oxyDEAfT6oSd6AoLGVxvdIuRiWbeHiHKAA). Same object defined in javascript works just fine but in typescript, there is some error being thrown which I'm unable to understand.

Comment: What is `configUrl()` and `config`? Ideally your question should explicitly state what your issue is (it has something to do with inferring types, but you have not spelled out what and where the problem is), and where someone could take your [mcve] code and drop it as-is into a standalone IDE like [the TypeScript Playground (link)](//tsplay.dev/WzoORw) and demonstrate the issue for themselves without other unrelated problems distracting things. My guess is that this is is something like [ms/TS#39133](//github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/39133) but I'll wait for edits here.

Comment: I feel like this object could be made a little less complex, also.  As it is right now, it's a tuple of a string and a map where the map has a string as the key but the value but could be an object, another map, or an array of objects.  Making these more consistent might make defining your types easier.

Comment: Hey @jcalz I have edited my answer and made it more comprehensible. Would you like to have a look at it now?

Comment: @sma I understand what you're trying to convey but restructuring the object will break our entire codebase and we cannot afford that now. We just want to convert a few things from javascript to typescript.

Comment: Does [this](https://tsplay.dev/wEDvyW) meet your needs?  If so, I'll write up an answer explaining it.  If not, please edit your question with use cases that show how it doesn't work for you.

Comment: Sorry for the delay but this seems like the solution I was looking for. I did figured a solution but the way you have defined the types definitely looks way more clean and precise than mine. Thanks for your time and assistance!

Comment: Okay, I will write up an answer when I get a chance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This seems to be a design limitation or bug in the typings for [the `Map` constructor](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map/Map); see [microsoft/TypeScript#39133](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/39133) for more information about a similar issue.  Currently when you call `new Map()` the compiler tries to match it to one of three [overloads](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/functions.html#function-overloads); one where you pass in [no argument](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/blob/8cdcec4454d0afe90cf67a6ecf2410d11c2f486c/lib/lib.es2015.collection.d.ts#L32), one where you pass in an [array of entries](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/blob/8cdcec4454d0afe90cf67a6ecf2410d11c2f486c/lib/lib.es2015.collection.d.ts#L33) and one where you pass in a [general *iterable* of entries](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/blob/main/lib/lib.es2015.iterable.d.ts#L160).  The two latter constructors are [generic](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html) in the key type `K` and value type `V` of the map being constructed.  When the array or iterable has keys of exactly one type and values of exactly one type, there's no problem.  But the limitation you're running into is that the compiler isn't able to automatically infer `K` or `V` if either of them should be of a [union](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#union-types) type.

In your case, the key type is `string`, but the value type seems to be a union, which is throwing off the compiler.  It looks like you have a basic value type of the following form:

```
interface Test {
  test: 'equal' | 'include' | 'notInclude',
  expected: string;
};
```

Your `Map` will hold values of type `Test`, but it will also hold values of *arrays* or other *`Map`s* of that type.  That is, the value type seems like a recursively-defined union:

```
type TestValue = Test | Map<string, TestValue> | Array<TestValue>;
```

It's possible you have some slightly different constraints, but this is my guess based on the example.  Anyway, once we have decided that your map has keys of type `string` and values of type `TestValue`, then we can *manually* specify the `K` and `V` generics when we call the `Map` constructor, as `new Map<string, TestValue>(...)`:

```
const TESTS = [
  ['reminderEmail', new Map<string, TestValue>([
    ['subject', { test: 'equal', expected: 'Kindly complete your setup' }],
    ['headers', new Map([
      ['X-Link', { test: 'equal', expected: 'someUrl' }],
      ['X-Template-Name', { test: 'equal', expected: 'reminderFirst' }],
      ['X-Template-Version', { test: 'equal', expected: 'someVersion' }],
    ])],
    ['html', [
      { test: 'include', expected: "Here&#x27;s your reminder" },
      { test: 'include', expected: 'someUrl' },
      { test: 'include', expected: 'someUrl' },
      { test: 'include', expected: 'device' },
    ]],
    ['text', [
      { test: 'include', expected: "Here's your reminder" },
      { test: 'notInclude', expected: 'someUrl' },
      { test: 'notInclude', expected: 'someUrl' },
      { test: 'notInclude', expected: 'utm_source=email' },
    ]],
  ])],
];
```

And now there's no error.

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgCoQM5mQbwFDLKRYBcyA5BAI4CucANucgD4WgL00AmETr5IAPZgAkiA7deAGgLIIADwAOEBJC5ksUUAHMA3HgC++vGACeytJjAA1BjRQBeS1hbIAsnEUAeTTqnObOwgAPlcAQSgoOFMvdCxbThDjBEEQF1QAUQBlVCzkJwBtWQLyKAgAW1AeKAzyuGBGfxAIAHd3Tx8wLRBtfzjAxOCACiLCQhKMGgAjACsVMHJ-HCIrMkpaBkW5JXmIdQoAaSr6U2QU8sV6CEhkU0EaKGQMa5pFJgMAXRkx5BKACwgcGqGC2zTaHkUI1kPxKAA0ALQAGVAAGststiGA1tQ6I1tspVHs1hhBOUIABVKCMZCfb4-X7kBHoC70OCQeEAOTgZPRK1IFBxm38CgJajWZUqIGqADFgFAsO8vtCxnD4czLmyIPDrNAMMBUrzMdiNniRbt9uQSWSdfL9SBFXTCB8AJRKmHkP5gcp40b0jGrNjiTg8LZmwn7ABEAAloBAAGQAYnkACYAOy6DC3e6PCVVaARmmOsb+-nkdjB6T483E0kUqnvIuEEtYwMSEPCnbhmtkynUgyN3B8ltloOSUOdsUUHgAN2ASAbyo+bpV5Eg8gW-l9P2ba3LY47oqJyGjsctWYeyFzUvzheVTaHayEolH7arXYoVrrfYHO4oT7EbaVmGk6WrWvYLvSg5Gn+wgARW46HhaNBegA+iSDxIA4FT1N+i7Li6SofMYQA)